# Python3 multiprocessing terminate vs kill vs close

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I get what `terminate` and `kill` do. What does `close()` do?

Here is the quote from the python docs:

> Close the Process object, releasing all resources associated with it.
>   ValueError is raised if the underlying process is still running. Once
>   close() returns successfully, most other methods and attributes of the
>   Process object will raise ValueError.

It seems to me, this is the most useless call ever:

- if the process is still running, it does nothing, but fails with an exception
- if the process has already terminated... It is either busy cleaning up, or finished doing that, why would I ever want to call an explicit `close()` on it? (Could the use of this call be OS dependent?)

Could it be that this doc entry is just extremely awkward, and somehow it does mean that `close()` have the power to terminate a thread, but it only does that at certain python-defined checkpoints?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[The issue that added that method](https://bugs.python.org/issue30596) explains:

> `multiprocessing.Process` (actually, the `_popen` object attached to it) has a GC-based finalizer to release system resources (such as fds).  However, it would be nice to be able to release those resources in a timely manner.  Adding a `close()` method would let users do that.

Basically, without `close`, certain resources (file descriptors used for communicating with the parent, the `sentinel` handle, what have you) are only closed when the `Process` is garbage collected, which on non-CPython interpreters, or even CPython in the case of reference cycles, might occur at some non-deterministic time in the future.

The existence of `close` allows you to ensure the resources are definitely cleaned at a specific point in time, so, for example, a process that is launching many `Process`es can ensure file descriptors are cleaned up promptly to prevent running into a `ulimit` or kernel imposed file descriptor limit.

The normal use case would be to call `.close()` immediately after `.join()` (or `.kill()` or `.terminate()`); the `Process` would *eventually* release the resources even if you don't do that, but it might not happen immediately.

Comment: short answer: call `.close()` after `.join()` (or `.kill()` or `.terminate()`). because `close()` can release resources.